# HTML5 wordpress theme on WebKit goes crazy?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, google-chrome, webkit

I was testing WP HTML5 theme, when I spotted this bug. The whole content lowered by about 19px, and when I turned on source code, code which I placed between head tags in editor are between body tags in chrome source code. This is showing just on Webkit browsers (Chrome and Opera), while on Firefox it is fine.

I tried to fix this bug with:

```
-webkit-margin-before: -16px;
```

but this is not working for **page** template in WP theme, because there is no bug when I run any Wordpress page sample on Chrome. I tried to copy code from page template (page.php) to article template (single.php), and know they are running on same code but there is difference in appearance (look at screenshot).

[screenshot](http://www.dodaj.rs/f/v/vO/jAKlXbp/problem.png)

Code of a both templates (page.html and single.html):

```
<?php

  get_header();

  if (have_posts()): 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article class="postWrapper" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <div class="thumb">
                <?php 
                  the_post_thumbnail();
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="post-text">
                <p class="category">
                    <?php the_category(' &#187; '); ?>
                </p>
                <h2 class="article-title postTitle">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_excerpt(); ?>">

                            <?php the_title(); ?>

                    </a>
                </h2>
                <p class="details">
                    <?php the_date(); ?> Autor: <strong><?php the_author_link(); ?></strong>, <?php comments_popup_link(__('Nema komentara'), __('1 komentar'), __('% komentara')) . edit_post_link(__('Izmeni'), ' | '); ?>
                </p>
                <div class="text">
                    <?php the_content(__('Pročitaj više...')); ?>
                </div>
            </div>

    </article>



    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

  <p><?php _e('Žao nam je, nismo ništa pronašli što vas interesuje. :('); ?></p>

<?php

  endif;
  ?>
</div>

<?php
    get_sidebar();  ?>
    </div>
<?php

    get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: This is not an issue with the Wordpress HTML 5. This is an issue with your abstracted version of the Wordpress HTML 5 theme, and without having access to the live site, we will never be able to resolve it. Even if we could, it would be a length back and forth. Push the site to an IP that can be accessed from a non-local environment.

Comment: [link](http://domaceserije.org/mltutorijali/test/test2/) Here is live site

Answer (score 0):

The problem was about encoding in Notepad++, I used UTF-8, but when I switched on UTF-8 without BOM, problem disappeard.